# BitmapFactory : EACCS

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bitmap

I have nearly spent 1 week for this problem but since i cant solve it, i will post it here. My goal is to save a taken picture as bitmap and set it to an `ImageView`.

The `OnactivityResult`-Method :

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
                System.out.println("We are in resultCode Activity.Result_OK");
                //for thumbnail:
                //Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Bitmap bm = StorageController.readCardImage(activity.getCurrentCard().getUUID());
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
```

The `readCardImage`-Method:

```
public static Bitmap readCardImage(final String uuid) {
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File file = new File(storageDir, "JPEG_" + uuid + ".jpg");
    Bitmap bm = null;
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Yes the File exists actually");

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Uuuups Picture Image does not exist");
    }
    return bm;
}
```

And the `createCardImage`-Method:

```
public static File createCardImageFile(final String uuid) {
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = null;
    try {
        image = new File(storageDir, "JPEG_" + uuid + ".jpg");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Image path to Save = " + image.getAbsolutePath());
    return image;

}
```

**What error do i get?**

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_617d34d2-0388-4950-b5f9-d03686458fa6.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**What have i tried so far?**

1. Check if file actually exists (YES)
2. Check if createCard and saveCard have the same file name (YES)
3. Granted manual permission and added permission in manifest (YES)

This is so strange, since it works with my other mobile phone, but NOT on my HTC and NOT on the emulator. 
EDIT : targetSdk is 23